# libpcap getting the process ID of a packet

Tags: c++, linux, libpcap

I'm currently working on a project that will monitor the network usage of my system. One feature I'm planning on adding is the ability to get the usage of a specific process (upload and download). The library I'm using is libpcap. Is there any way I can get the process ID of a packet without using a third party library? Are there any third party libraries that I can use if libpcap doesn't have the process ID? I'm developing this on Linux, but I do want it to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the process ID isn't in the packet, so libpcap won't have it, so you're going to have to grapple with operating-system specific stuff to relate the port to a processID.

You could investigate SNMP, specificaly the TCPConnTable and TCPConnectionTable. One or other is supported on most platforms, if not necessarily enabled by default.

Comment: I want to get the process id of all packets, not just limited to TCP, such as http and UDP. Will this method still work?. Sorry if I sound like an idiot, I'm relatively new to network protocols.

Comment: HTTP is still TCP. UDP data is also available via SNMP.